# Html for response when i want a string

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, json, ajax

I have the function below:

```
function getHtmlFromMarkdown(markdownFormat, requestUrl) {

    const dataValue = { "markdownFormat": markdownFormat }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: requestUrl,
        data: dataValue,
        contentType: "application/json: charset = utf8",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
            document.getElementById("generatedPreview").innerHTML = response;
        },
        fail: function () {
            alert('Failed')
        }
    });
}
```

And i have this on my server:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GenerateHtmlFromMarkdown(string markdownFormat)
    {
        string htmlFormat = "Some text";

        return htmlFormat;
    }
```

I have on response html code, not the string that i want. What am I doing wrong?
And if i change the "dataType: json" it doesn't even enter either the success nor fail functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this.

```
function getHtmlFromMarkdown(markdownFormat, requestUrl) {
var obj={};
obj.markdownFormat=markdownFormat;


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: requestUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
        document.getElementById("generatedPreview").innerHTML = response.d;
    },
    failure: function () {
        alert('Failed')
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I still don't get the alert

Comment: It should work. Is it calling your code behind method?? Put a breakpoint and check.

Comment: I have tested it.

Comment: I didn't saw the "failure" tag. It didn't work with fail. I think the problem is in the url,and that's why my function is not called

Comment: failure function callback is available ?

Comment: I changed the tag with error and now i get the alert 'Failed'. So it works...not as i wanted, but now i get something

Comment: But that mean your method was not called. Try my solution with failure tag you should get the value "some text".

Comment: I copy pasted your code and you are right indeed, it works like a charm. But i don't understand what .d is doing and i don't see what i did wrong :)

Comment: .d is there because your return type is JSON. It is recommended. Mark the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: And can you explain a little the part with obj? Why did i have to do that and not just give the string to data

Comment: With obj you are creating a sort of object. And then assign those values which are your parameters in the WebMethod. And the use JSON.stringify to convert to json. I use this so that I don't mess up my JSON string to pass to WebMethod.it always works.

Comment: @Sami i also have modified my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your data type of ajax must be json like this

```
function getHtmlFromMarkdown(markdownFormat, requestUrl) {
    var dataValue = { "markdownFormat": markdownFormat }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: requestUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(dataValue),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
            document.getElementById("generatedPreview").innerHTML = response;
        },
        error: function () { alert("Failed"); }
    });
}
```

Comment: if i change the datatype to json i don't get the alerts at all

Comment: Well, this doesn't fix my problem fully, but at least now i know that the problem is not here because now i get the error alert. Thank you